# Website caching failover service

Tags: failover

A while back I remember reading about a service that provided failover support for websites. I never got around to reading specifics and now I can't remember the name of the service. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks, Larry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this might be [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/).

Comment: Answering with a question?